# Adding artifactory hosted repository to nexus

Tags: artifactory, nexus

Trying to figure out how to add an artifactory repository to nexus repository manager OSS..

Specifically, https://software.r3.com/artifactory/corda/

When added as proxy repo, I cannot for the life of me get it to populate 'browse index' or 'browse storage'...   'browse remote' displays all dirs/files just fine.

running Nexus Repository Manager OSS 2.12.0-01

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out.

It does not mirror or index the entire repository, it only pulls files specifically asked for by maven during build process.